# CSS not loaded in Prime NG Schedule

Tags: angular, primeng

I've got a problem with Prime NG Schedule css loading, in effect it looks like on a [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcAfu.jpg).  Project is a standard VS2017 template that is using .net core 2.0 and angular 4. There is no angular-cli.json file (I've added it, but it didn't help) and no system.config.js also.

Any idea how to load css properly?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to [create your Angular project with the CLI](https://cli.angular.io).  Then locate the `angular-cli.json` file and the `styles` section therein.  Also, use `npm` to install primeng.  Then make that section look like this:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ],
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should import following css to your styles.scss file

```
@import url("../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css");
@import url("../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css");
```

this should fix issue.